# Display the value from laravel relationship?

Tags: mongodb, laravel, relationship

I am using laravel 5.1 with mongodb, I need to display users list on a blade, i am using Laravel relationship method(hasMany), i tried but i got

```
error(Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$roles)
```

Table structure:

```
users-> userid, username,email, roleid.
user_roles->roleid,rolename;
```

my question is simple, i want userdetails from user table with rolename, i have attached my query result image.any suggesstion please?
Controller:

```
$users =User::with('roles')->get();
return view('Manage_users', compact('users'));
```

User Model:

```
class User extends Eloquent 
{
  protected $collection = 'users';

  public function roles()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\User_role','roleid','roleid');
    }

}
```

User_roles Model:

```
class User_role extends Eloquent
{
  protected $collection = 'user_roles';


  public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User','roleid','rolename');
    }
}
```

[My query result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDqa0.png)

[My view page result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qczkd.png)

Answer (score 1):

in controller update your code to this

```
$users = User::with('roles')->whereHas('roles', function ($query) {
                                   $query->where('roleid', '>', 0);
                                })->get();
return view('Manage_users', compact('users'));
```

Comment: Its returning, empty array, 
 Collection {#215 ▼
  #items: []
}

Comment: @MuMuthukumar Is it possible that some users may not have any role assigned?

Comment: No, all users have some role like admin,contractor,inspector

Comment: @MuMuthukumar yes you are right. Rather creating complex query we can check it using `$model->exists('roles')` property

Comment: @MuMuthukumar try chaging $this->hasMany('App\User_role','roleid','roleid'); to hasOne() in user model

Comment: @ParthShah As per his Image link he is getting correct output. He just wants to show in his view.

Comment: @VaibhavrajRoham he is getting roles as array of collections.. if there is only one role assigned to each user.. relationship should be hasOne() so he can access it directly without using index

Comment: @ParthShah I agree.

Comment: @MuMuthukumar try my answered code after changing relationship to hasOne()

Comment: @ParthShah if i use hasOne(),  i am getting Trying to get property of non-object , if i use hasMany(), i am getting undefined property..

Answer (score 0):

You are wrong with eloquent, and relationship.
A user belongs to a role, a role has many users.

from user Model:

```
public function role()
{
   return $this->belongsTo('App\User_role','roleid','id');
}
```

from user_roles model:

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\User','roleid','id');
}
```

Comment: User may have multiple roles. what do you think @ray-cheng?

Comment: No, one user have only one role

Comment: @VaibhavrajRoham, one user have one role, from table structure you can get that.

Comment: i can't get you@VaibhavrajRoham

Comment: @RayCheng is correct on this one if a user can only have a single role assigned to them. With this relationship you can do as @Vaibhavraj-Roham suggests and do this `$user->role->rolename` provided `$user` is an instance of a `User` object

Comment: Yes I agree @RayCheng

Comment: My query is - $users =User::with('roles')->get();     i am getting the error "Call to undefined method Jenssegers\Mongodb\Query\Builder::roles()"

Answer (score 0):

you can use following code  in your view.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>User Name</th>
        <th>Role</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach($users as $user)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $user->username }}</td>
            <td>{{ $user->roles->rolename }}</td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach

</table>
```

Above  code will create the table with username and it's role.

Hope it helps you!

Comment: as per [this image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDqa0.png) above answer should work

Comment: it shows error "Trying to get property of non-object "

Comment: It will fail (as error) if there is no role assigned to user.

Comment: By default all user have role id

Comment: You are not passing users variable to view. use `return view('Manage_users')->with(['users' => $users]);`

Comment: Same error - Trying to get property of non-object (View: /home/new/LAMP/apache2/htdocs/FieldiLaravelMongo/resources/views/Manage_users.blade.php)

Comment: dump `$users` variable `dd($users)` in view and provide the output image.

Comment: i have already attached dd($users) output, my view page result is https://i.stack.imgur.com/qczkd.png

Answer (score 0):

Its working after i change my blade like this, Thanks for all

```
@foreach($users as $user)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $user->username }}</td>
        <td>
            @if ($user->roles)
                {{ $user->roles->rolename }}
            @endif
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```